# asp.net mvc How do you update a database when you update an item in it (database not updating correctly)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this function which updates certain information in a student (user)

```
public static bool UpdateStudent(this DBEntities1 DB, StudentView studentView)
        {
            Student studentToUpdate = DB.Students.Find(studentView.idStudent);
            studentView.CopyToStudent(studentToUpdate);
            DB.Entry(studentToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
            DB.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
```

When student changes information on himself, there is no problem, the database is updated no problem. The issue is that when an admin changes information (deactivates the account), it changes the value in the database, but only on the side of the admin. From the student side, he is not affected by the changes but the admin sees him as deactivated and when I check the database, the student is seen as deactivated. It is like when the student logs in, he takes the old value he had before in the database instead of the new value.
This is the function that deactivates the student:

```
public static bool DeactivateStudent(this DBEntities1 DB, StudentView studentView)
        {

            OnlineStudents.RemoveSessionStudent(studentView); //tried to see if it was taking the student from the online session

            studentView.active = false;
            BeginTransaction(DB);
            if (studentView.admitted) //delete rep if accepted
            {
                DB.Representatives.Remove(DB.FindRepbyStudentId(studentView.idStudent));
                studentView.admitted = false;
            }
            DB.UpdateStudent(studentView);
            AddDeletedStudent(DB, studentView); //add deleted student
            
            if (InscriptionExist(DB, studentView.idStudent)) //delete inscription
                DeleteStudentInscription(DB, studentView.idStudent);

            DB.WriteStudentLog(studentView.idStudent, LogActions.deleteAccount);
            DB.SaveChanges();
            Commit();
            return true;
        }
```

I don't understand why on one side it takes the new database values and the other one doesn't. When I shut the application off and restart it, the student then has the new information that was updated.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you use DB.Students.Find (studentView.idStudent) to find the student to update, with the StudentView.CopyToStudent method you probably only update the data you need (thus preventing overpost) and then save the changes.

The second procedure seems less clear to me. In the second case, try to use the same procedure, except that only the admitted flag will be updated.

Perhaps you could also consider treating concurrency conflicts.

Comment: Well, I do use the same procedure in the second function, it just has extra steps because I change other things in the database when I deactivate a student. It's just that everything is updated except from the students point of view when he connects to the database.